# How can I fix a revoked certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate

I seem to be caught in the 9th circle of certificate/profile/signing hell. I get this notice from apple when attempting to test a little learner app on my iPhone:

```
The following certificate has either been revoked by a member of your development team or has expired: 
Certificate: iOS Development
```

Here are the conditions:

MBP running 10.13.4

Iphone 6+ with iOS 12.4.1

Xcode 9.4

More info:

I formerly had an Apple Developer Program paid membership which expired in 2017. I did not renew it, because I'm just learning and have nothing to distribute. I started trying to learn Swift, and for a while had no trouble testing my apps on my iPhone. Then an injury interrupted my efforts for around a year. Now, my attempts (using Ray Wenderlich's excellent site) to build and run my project on the iPhone go nowhere, and I get this:

```
Code Signing Error: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct.
Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'com.radianimagery.HitList' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.radianimagery.HitList'.
Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.4'
```

Here's what I see in the "Signing" section of the app:

[image]

I've tried the developer website, looked through questions on SO (most pretty old), and I'm just plain stuck. I downloaded all my certificates, then hit "Manage Certificates." I get this window, indicating that all my thrashing this morning created more certificates, but I can't seem to do anything with them:

[image]

I admit upfront that this whole certificate/profile side of things has always mystified me. That having been said, can anyone please help me get back on track?

TIA

**EDIT**

***I finally had to create a new user account on my MBP, then a new Apple ID. then I joined under that Apple ID, and everything has been peachy since.
Many thanks to all who responded!***

Comment: Is your apple developer program still active? If yes, XCode should have an `Automatically manage signing` options and you no need to worry about the cert now. If that does not work, you can always go to http://developers.apple.com to create your own cert

Comment: If you have a developer membership, just click the + button at the bottom and create a new development identity / certificate. If you have no developer membership, get one.

Comment: @matt-- If you mean paid membership, I did have one, but it expired in 2017. All I want now is to be able to test my apps on my iPhone, with no plans at the moment to distribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your Apple ID password may have changed since you last used Xcode - that would explain your `Code Signing Error: The user name or passphrase you entered is not correct` error. Try navigating to Xcode > Preferences... and view the Accounts tab, and check for any errors there. Xcode may prompt you to sign in again with your Apple ID.

Comment: I checked as you suggested, but everything is in order with as Apple ID and password...